# What is the fastest way of finding non-empty cells in a matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, big-o, office-js

I am working with Office.js development, you don't need to know anything about it since the question relates more to Javascript. In Excel you can get a matrix of formulas with a function, that is an array of arrays.

Usually there are A LOT of empty values and only couple filled values. Now, I want to find these filled values with their indexes.

Is it possible to do this in Javascript with less then O(n * m) complexity given a matrix (n * m)

Thanks

I can't think of a solution other than one by one looping through each cell in the matrix.

Comment: depending on what you are trying to achieve you can convert to html and use a regex to find the blank cells

Comment: @ControlAltDel I think controlling a selection of 1million x 100000 table might be hard to convert to HTML :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using `Array.prototype.reduce()` to achieve this. However, to find these values, you'll need to examine each element at least once, so the complexity won't be lower than `O(n * m)` in the worst case.

Here's an example of how you might do it using `reduce()`:

```js
function findNonEmptyIndices(matrix) {
  return matrix.reduce((acc, row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((cell, colIndex) => {
      if (cell !== null && cell !== undefined && cell !== '') {
        acc.push({ rowIndex, colIndex, value: cell });
      }
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

// Example usage:
const myMatrix = [
  [null, '', 5, null],
  [8, null, '', 10],
  ['', 20, null, 'hello'],
];

const nonEmptyIndices = findNonEmptyIndices(myMatrix);
console.log(nonEmptyIndices);
```

This function `findNonEmptyIndices()` loops through each element of the matrix using `reduce()`. When it encounters a non-empty cell, it records its row index, column index, and value into an array of objects. This way, you end up with an array containing the indices and values of non-empty cells.

Comment: In worst case scenario this will be O(n*m) right?

Comment: Yes, in the worst-case scenario, the time complexity will be O(n * m).

Comment: By applying some optimizations we can improve the speed of search, but the fundamental nature of needing to inspect each element to identify non-empty values means the complexity won't be lower than O(n * m) in such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

For Office.js I have found an easier solution. Instead of looking at matrix of formulas. There is a function that let's you get cells by type.

range.getSpecialCells("Formulas", "All");

With this i am directly getting a list of formulas.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).